# Is there a closed form product of $\cos(kx)$?

Tags: trigonometry, products

Is there a closed form for
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)$$
where $n>0$ is an integer?

---

This was proposed as $\prod_{k=1}^n a^k+\overline{a^k}$ where $a$ is a complex number, in the book of Claude Deschamps and Andre Warusfel (a French book).

Comment: yes there is a closed form which conains the Pochhammer-function

Comment: Try to see this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971805/proving-the-formula-for-%24%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En-%5Ccos%28kx%29%24. You can find more on SearchOnMath.