# Proving the formula for $\prod_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I'm trying to find a closed-form for the following product:

$$ \prod_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)$$

---

Here is my attempt at it:

$$ \prod_{k=1}^n \cos(2kx) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{ e^{i2kx} + e^{-i2kx} }{2} = \frac{(e^{2ix} - e^{-2ix}) \prod_{k=1}^n  e^{i2kx} + e^{-i2kx}  }{2^n (e^{i2x}- e^{-i2x})}= \frac{1}{2^n (e^{i2x}- e^{-i2x})} ( e^{4inx} - e^{-4inx} )= \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{\sin(4nx)}{\sin(2x)} $$

The above was simplified by using the algebraic identity $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2 -b^2$ repeatedly in the product. Now sub:$  x \to \frac{x}{2}$

$$ \prod_{k=1}^n \cos( kx)= \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin x}$$

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when I plug $ x= \frac{\pi}{n}$, I'm not getting the result as shown in this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173238/evaluating-the-product-prod-limits-k-1n-cos-left-frack-pin-right?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Edit: Whoops! The algebraic manipulation doesn't hold after k=3 as correctly pointe od out by @leon. However, still am looking for a closed form.

Comment: You can't use  your "algebraic identity repeatedly" because there is $e^{i6x}$ in the product.

Comment: good point @Leon

Comment: I think you're confusing $2k$ with $2^k.$

Answer (score 1):

Your result seems to be wrong for $n>1$, because the limit as $x\to 0$ of the left hand side is $1$, whereas the limit as $x\to 0$ of the r.h.s is $\frac{2n}{2^n}$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Mathematica for `Product[Cos[k x],{k,n}]` returns

```
2^(-1 - n)*E^((I/2)*n*(1 + n)*x)*QPochhammer[-1, E^((-2*I)*x), 1 + n]
```

which in usual mathematical notation using
the [Q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) is
$\; 2^{-1-n}e^{i n(n+1)x/2} (-1;e^{-2ix})_{n+1}. $

Once the closed form of the product is known, it is not hard to
prove it using the definition of the Q-Pochhammer symbol
$$ (a;q)_n := \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^k). $$

Comment: What is $n+1$? ss

Comment: @Behemooth It is part of the Q-Pochhammer symbol. The Wikipedia link has details. Thanks for asking.